# SQLite and VARCHAR - Line Breaks

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite

I have a problem with my database using SQLite Manager. I have created a field with VARCHAR type and I am retrieving the mySQL entry using javascript. I have a paragraph of text I am trying to retrieve that I need line breaks in because it just pulls all the information in. I have tried `<br>` `/n` and a few others but it always just shows them and doesn't do the line break. Can anyone help me out with this problem? The code I am using to retrieve my text is here:

```
for (var i=0; i < len; i = i + 1) {
        treat = results.rows.item(i);
        $("#warning").append("<li class='treatment'>" + treat.Tips + "</li>");
        $("#warning-text").text(treat.Tips);
        $('#warning').listview('refresh');
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL has no built-in mechanism to escape special characters inside strings.

However, you can just use the line break itself:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES('line
break');
```

If you have a recent enough SQLite version, you can use the [char() function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#char):

```
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES('line' || char(10) || 'break');
```

Comment: I have multiple sentences in each field of the SQL column. This line break will only effect after each field and not each sentence correct?

Comment: A line break will have an effect only at the place where you use it.